# Add an DelegationHandler (outgoing request middleware) to TestServer's HttpClient

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Is it possible to add a custom `DelegationHandler` (outgoing request middleware) to the `HttpClient` built by the asp.net core `TestServer`?

I'm trying to combine the [customization possibilities](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers) of using `HttpClientFactory` to influence `HttpClients` with the in-memory testing utility [`TestServer`](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/testserver.aspx):

```cs
public class ExternalProxySslDowngradeSimulator : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request,
            CancellationToken token)
     {
        if (request.RequestUri.Scheme == "https")
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(
                     request.RequestUri.OriginalString.Replace("https:", "http:"));

         return base.SendAsync(request, token);
     }
}

[TestFixture
public class TestClass
{
   [Test]
   public async Task CallApi()
   {
      var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((ctx, config) => { })
           .UseUrl("http://customDomain.com")
           .UseStartup<CustomApi.Startup>();

      var testServer = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.TestServer(builder);

      var httpClient = testServer.CreateClient();

      var apiResult = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://customDomain");
   }
}
```

**I can't find a way to plug my `DelegatingHandler` into the `HttpClient` returned from `testServer.CreateClient()`**

---

What I've tried so far:

1. [Registering a custom HttpClientBuilder](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers) (did not work):

```cs
// did not work:
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
   .UseStartup<CustomApi.Startup>()
   .ConfigureServices(services =>
   {
        services
          .AddHttpClient("")
          .AddHttpMessageHandler<ExternalProxySslDowngradeSimulator>();
```

Looking through the [code for `TestServer`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src) it is not hooking into that pipeline.

2. Custom `HttpClientFactoryOptions` (did not work)

Thought I could bind a custom `HttpClientFactoryOptions` and add a custom action to [`HttpClientFactoryOptions.HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.httpclientfactoryoptions.httpmessagehandlerbuilderactions?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_Http_HttpClientFactoryOptions_HttpMessageHandlerBuilderActions).  But the TestServer doesn't really consume this the way a default Http Client Factory does.

3. Customize the setup of `TestServer` (did not work)

Looking through the documentation / source didn't see anywhere to hook in.  There's an [extension method to further control DI](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs), but I didn't see how that could get me a hook into the custom `HttpMessangeHandler` that TestServer is using.

Answer (score 1):

So what you do is create your own client using the test server's (Server in code example) CreateHandler method and the HttpClientFactory.Create method.

```
var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(Server.CreateHandler(), new CustomDelegate() );
client.BaseAddress = Server.BaseAddress;
```

This took me forever to figure out. Hopefully this helps you.

So your example would be

```
var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(testServer.CreateHander(), new ExternalProxySslDowngradeSimulator());
httpClient.BaseAddress = testServer.BaseAddress;
```

Comment: interesting.  I'd given up on solving this problem and moved on.  I'll have to track down my old project and see if this solved it!